# Expo for Web failed to compile because of native base module

Tags: react-native, expo, native-base, react-native-web

I'm trying to get the "expo for web" part working for my managed expo project.

I upgraded my managed expo project to expo sdk 33 so that I could also deploy my app on the web platform and ideally have it hosted from firebase.
I followed official instructions from expo:

[Upgrading Expo SDK Walkthrough](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v33.0.0/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/)

[Expo CLI and SDK web support beta](https://blog.expo.io/expo-cli-and-sdk-web-support-beta-d0c588221375)

[Using Expo for web in a expo init project](https://github.com/expo/web-examples/blob/master/expo-managed-workflow/README.md)

on how to upgrade to SDK 33 and how to configure and enable the web platform.

Expo-cli version is : '2.19.5'

I'm using Yarn

**package.json**

```js
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "latest",
    "expo": "next",
    "expo-cli": "^2.19.5",
    "expo-codemod": "^1.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "latest",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "latest",
    "expo-image-picker": "latest",
    "expo-intent-launcher": "latest",
    "expo-permissions": "latest",
    "firebase": "^5.8.1",
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-firebaseui": "^3.1.2",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-alert-async": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-modal": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^5.2.3",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.4",
    "react-navigation": "^3.5.0-alpha.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "schedule": "0.4.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "prettier": "1.16.4"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "jsxBracketSameLine": true,
    "arrowParens": "always",
    "bracketSpacing": false
  },
  "private": true
}
```

This is the error I'm getting, Sorry I'm not sure at all
how to fix it. I have updated expo and native base to the latest versions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Failed to compile.
/node_modules/native-base-shoutem- 
theme/src/StyleProvider.js 10:19
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:19)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|  */
| export default class StyleProvider extends React.Component {
>   static propTypes = {
|     children: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
|     style: PropTypes.object,
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the Webpack config used by Expo CLI will automatically transpile any `node_modules` that start with `expo`, `react-native`, `react-navigation`, `@expo`, `@react-navigation`. Any other modules need to be manually added to the config file either by creating a new webpack config that extends `@expo/webpack-config` or by adding the module name to the `app.json` like so: https://github.com/hectahertz/react-native-typography/pull/31

```js
"expo": {
  ...
  "web": {
    "build": {
      "babel": {
        "include": [
          "native-base-shoutem-theme"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting the same error it's not resolved my problem.

"description": "",
    "web": {
      "build": {
        "babel": {
          "include": [
            "native-base-shoutem-theme"
          ]
        }
      }
    }