# Implement Docz on a project with native-base

Tags: react-native, babeljs, native-base, metro-bundler

### Question

Hey, guys. I'm trying to document my React-Native project using Docz. Thing is my project is using Native-Base.

**Description**
When I try to build, I keep getting this error:

```
./node_modules/native-base-shoutem-theme/src/StyleProvider.js 10:19
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:19)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|  */
| export default class StyleProvider extends React.Component {
>   static propTypes = {
|     children: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
|     style: PropTypes.object,
```

This is my doczrc.js file:

```
import { reactNative } from 'docz-plugin-react-native';

export default {
  title: 'Recarga Styleguide',
  plugins: [reactNative()],
  native: true,
  src: './app/components/ui/' // <== where the components are located inside the project
};
```

I've been researching and it seems to be quite a common error with Native-Base.
I found this solution in stackoverflow:
[[Expo for Web failed to compile because of native base module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56586865/expo-for-web-failed-to-compile-because-of-native-base-module](Expo) for Web failed to compile because of native base module)

I suspect this solution might work for me, thing is: I don't think my project is using expo. I think I would like to try some setting on my babel.config or metro.config file, but I'm not sure how it would work.

Could you help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When I checked the library you used, I realized that it was [Docs](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) `Deprecated`
I recommend using this library [THIS](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web)  as the library itself recommends

Comment: I'll check this out. Thank you!